# Master/Detail flow has minimum api level equal to that in use

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest, android-studio

When i try to create a new Master/Detail flow activity in Android Studio i am told "The activity Master/Detail Flow has a minimum SDK level of 11.". I understand why this is, but I don't understand why i am being prevented from creating this activity as the min SDK as defined by my AndroidManifest.xml is 11.

I created with a lower minimum but have since changed to 11. When i create a new project with a miniumum of 11, and then change the manifest to use 7 as min SDK I can create a new Master/Detail flow activity. This makes me think there is a project property i need to change, but I cannot find it!

I have tried so far:

- downloading all SDKs from 11 upwards
- Rebuilding project
- Invalidating cache and restarting
- setting Min, Target and Max SDK to 18
- creating a new activity with "Power save mode" on

[image: Here's a pic of the error next to my min SDK version]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be late answer but i found same problem.

Here is solution. On your build.gradle there will be following line

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

just change minSdkVersion to 11 and click "Sync Project with Gradel File" icon, then try to create Activity again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, that was it! The defaultConfig was still set to min 11. I've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Problem occurred with minimum required sdk, I guess, you have `API 18: Android 2.2 (Froyo)`. Just change it to `API 11`.